# getattrib: NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: samba

This used to work but after a samba server upgrade anything that I am trying to "get" via an smbclient is returning "getattrib: NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED"

In my client, I simply execute smbclient //mypc//sharename -Uusername and then I key in the password. This works ok and I can see directory listing and traverse into the directories.

As soon as I try to pull a file using smb's get command, it gives me this error

getattrib: NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED

The only thing that changed was an updated Samba server. My smbclient is up to date and I am sure it should be some configuration in smb.conf

PS: Before this problem I wasn't able to connect, and had to add client max protocol = SMB3 not sure if this helps.

I am trying to use smbclient in my Ubuntu to get a file from a Samba share into this ubuntu server. However, it gives me the mentioned error instead.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to use smbclient in my Ubuntu to get a file from a Samba share into this ubuntu server. However, it gives me the mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

Setup Samba service for "URL file inclusion":

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

under `[global]` paste:

```
client min protocol = NT1
server min protocol = NT1
```

Under `[printers]` paste:

```
[htb]
  comment = RFI TEST
  browseable = yes
  path = /tmp/htb
  guest ok = yes
  writable = yes
  create mask = 0600
  directory mask = 0700
```

Restart Samba:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```